# Kendo dropdown and filter outside grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to adjust or change my dropdown and filter at above the grid. Anyone have the idea? Please see my demo at below. Thank you.

[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/INiCapUc)

Comment: Just move the filters above the grid ?

Comment: Yes, i want to it outside the grid and at above @Alexandre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my solution:

```
 <script src="../content/shared/js/products.js"></script>
</div>
  <div id="filters"><input id="ddl" /> <input id="text" type="text" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Filter by name" /></div>
<div id="example">
  <div id="grid">
  <script>
```

[Update for DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/INiCapUc/5)

Comment: Told you just to move filters and ddl right over the grid ^^ Glad you got it. Btw kendo is really amazing.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you for the tips! @Alexandre